# whatever happened to bit.ly bundles?

Tags: bit.ly

Bundles was a feature where you could group a bunch of related links together. Now I hear it has been removed...

http://venturebeat.com/2015/04/09/bitly-replaces-bundles-with-tags-to-help-users-organize-their-shortened-links/

But is there any plan for us to save those bundles via some mechanism? Or are they tagged somehow automatically in their system?

Or are they totally gone! :/